# Why does an autoResizeColumn() loop seem to freeze a Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

All I'm trying to do is resize all the columns in a spreadsheet. This is a standalone spreadsheet. I'm using:

```
function format() {
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp
    .openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheetIdHere/edit#gid=0")
    .getSheetByName("sheetName");
  var columns = destination.getMaxColumns();
  destination.setFrozenRows(1);
  destination.setFrozenColumns(3);
  for (var i = columns; i >= 1; i--) {
    Logger.log(i)
    destination.autoResizeColumn(i);
  }
}
```

I've tried both `for (var i = columns; i >= 1; i--)` and `for (var i = 1; i <= columns; i++)` just because I don't know what's causing it. I was assuming an endless loop, but I removed the loop entirely and it still runs for way too long.

The log produces expected results when I comment out the autoResize...  and in about a second. Bring back autoResize... and the script just runs and runs, and doesn't even change any columns.

I tried taking out the loop and putting a single number in `autoResizeColumn(227)` and that worked. Bring the loop back and I'm stuck.

Is autoResizeColums() just too slow, or am I missing something?

Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: try using getLastColumn() instead of getMaxColumn().
getLastColumn() gives you the index of the last column that contains data, while getMaxColumn() gives you the index of the total number of columns in a spreasheet.
The max number of columns in a standard google spreadsheet is 256.

Answer (score 0):

## Part 1

From the question:

> and the script just runs and runs, and doesn't even change any columns.

from [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush):

> Spreadsheet operations are sometimes bundled together to improve performance, such as when doing multiple calls to Range.getValue().

If  you want to see the changes made by your script to the spreadsheet before the script ends, you have to add `SpreadshsheetApp.flush()`. Bear in mind that but adding it inside a loop is mentioned in an example of bad practices on the official documentation<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>: [Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices)

## Part 2

From the question:

> Is autoResizeColums() just too slow, or am I missing something?

In general the calls to SpreadsheetApp and other similar services are very slow. In my own experience the slowest call that I saw is 9 seconds to write a user property by using the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)

Comment: I know, that's why i didn't add flush(). I don't need to see it, I'm just shocked at the time it takes to complete.

Comment: Please include that in your question.